# Defining 'package' information in component.json and package.json

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I'm creating a javascript library that I want make available through Bower to my internal company.  I'm using Grunt to build my library.

My issue is that grunt's convention is to use `package.json` to define dependencies, library versions, dependencies, etc.

Bower, on the other hand, assumes that that same information is found in a `component.json` file.

What's the intended use of these two?  They seem to serve essentially the same purpose. Do I need to create both and cut and paste the shared information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've gotten a lot of these kinds of question and everyone assumes we could share a lot metadata between these formats, but the reality is that only the `name` and `version` fields are sharable and only the `version` field changes regularly. If you find it cumbersome having to update two fields when you release something, there are tools out there that can automate this, eg. [grunt-bumpx](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-bumpx).

Answer (score 2):

`package.json` is intended for back-end purposes, in this case specify grunt tasks, node dependencies, etc. In the other side, `bower.json` is intended for front-end purposes.

Comment: This is also a good answer - between yourself and Sindre I think that's the full story.  Sorry Kevin!

Comment: Don't worry, my only purpose is to help ;)

Comment: `package.json` is **not** intended just for backend. npm works perfectly fine with the frontend as well.

Comment: Yes i know, but are you used to load your scripts and dependencies from node_modules folder? :P

Comment: Yes. I load js, css, images, html, binaries, etc from the node_modules folder. It works perfectly fine and there is no rule saying that you should not do it. So saying it is intended for back-end purposes is incorrect.