# Include JQuery with Package Manager - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm confused around all of the different tools such as Grunt, Bower, NPM, Gulp, etc...

What tool/package manager can I use to include/manage JQuery (and other JS libraries)?

Comment: You can get good information on these tools by googling each of them and what they achieve, if you are still unclear downloading your files and keeping them as a downloaded is fine if you are still learning web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bower to manage your front end libraries.

NPM is for installing packages to your backend, Bower is for installing libraries to your front end.

You will probably want to add the bower_components folder to your .gitignore (or equivalent if not using git)

Anyone who uses your repo can run bower install to get the front end libraries, the listing of libraries is kept in bower.json.  For a good list of Bower benefits see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/224828/why-should-i-use-bower/224832#224832?newreg=4db37e92ec744292bed67038a680cada

Grunt is a great tool for managing tasks that you have to do, in say your deployment process.  A grunt task could include minifying your code, here is a good example  grunt file  http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile

In terms of overall comparisons here's a better write up than I could do [Difference between Grunt, NPM and Bower ( package.json vs bower.json )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198977/difference-between-grunt-npm-and-bower-package-json-vs-bower-json)

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to add reasons for using Grunt + Bower in your answer?

Comment: Sure, I added a couple of additional sources that hopefully help out. If you have any more specific question just let me know!