# i want to know about package managers in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, package-managers

I have searched on internet but am unable to find complete solution of this question.

what is difference between pip , npm and bower in ubuntu and is there any other package manager for any other utility software?

I know there can be many utility software and their respective package manager but tell me about general utility softwares...

### **UPDATE**

---

**Now i know that my question does not make any sence because there are many package manages for different purpose in linux... - I have searched and found some of them.... - Several package managers and their description are as below....**

---

**Application-level package managers:**

- Anaconda: a package manager for Python
- Assembly: a partially compiled code library for use in Common
  Language Infrastructure (CLI) deployment, versioning and security
- Bower: a package manager for the web developers
- Cabal: a programming library and package manager for Haskell
- CocoaPods: Dependency Manager for Objective-C and RubyMotion projects
- Composer: Dependency Manager for PHP
- CPAN: a programming library and package manager for Perl
- CRAN: a programming library and package manager for R
- CTAN: a package manager for TeX
- EasyInstall: a package manager for Python and the PyPI programming
  library which is part of the Setuptools packaging system
- Gradle: a build system and package manager for Groovy and other JVM
  languages
- Ivy: a package manager for Java, integrated into the Ant build tool,
  also used by sbt
- LuaRocks: a programming library and package manager for Lua
- Maven: a package manager and build tool for Java
- npm: a programming library and package manager for Node.js
- NuGet: a package manager for the .NET Framework and C++
- PAR::Repository and Perl package manager: binary package managers for
  Perl
- PEAR: a programming library for PHP
- pip: a package manager for Python and the PyPI programming library
- Quicklisp: a package manager and repository for Common Lisp
- RubyGems: a package manager and repository for Ruby
- sbt: a build tool for Scala, uses Ivy for dependency management
- leiningen: a project automation tool for Clojure

Comment: Please refer this; it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198977/difference-between-grunt-npm-and-bower-package-json-vs-bower-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm is package manger for nodeJS (server side) application. and bower is library manager for front end (client side) development.

If you are looking for such dependency manager as npm is for node, then you can use composer for php.

and if you are looking for front end library manager then bower or gulp both are good enough.

Hope this answer satisfied your query