# How to interpret the syntax for npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39234812/1525840) I learned the importance of creating the file `packages.json` and putting in requirements for its dependencies. I do understand what the following two commands do and I've seen the effect of them in the file.

```
npm install require-dir --save-dev  
npm install lodash --save
```

I'm uncertain of a thing and it's the `require-dir` part. Is that a reserved word or something like that? Or are we free to use **anything** in order to create the entries in the `packages.json` file? Or am I reading it wrong and it's not "`require-dir`" but rather "`require`" and "`dir`" (or "`-dir`" maybe)?

And that leads me to the second part. I'm confused by the number of dashes in the syntax. Usually I see a single dash everywhere to indicate that something is a flag. E.g. `npm install typescript -global`. How should I interpret the double dash? Is it an empty flag in front of another flag (like `-null-save`) but compressed? Is it some kind of escape character?

Comment: That would be `-g` or `--global`, no? This isn't unique to `npm` generally or `install` specifically, you need to read up on using the command line.

Answer (score 1):

require-dir is a Node helper to require() directories and you are reading it right. Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir

And for the Two hyphen–minus characters ( -- ) they are generally used on some programs to specify "long options" where more descriptive option names are used.
For example, both The **-g** and **--global** argument will cause npm to install the package globally