# Do I need n_ when I already installed lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lodash

I'm reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39234812/1525840) that I should install *lodash*. However, at the [site of lodash](https://lodash.com/), they say that if I'm using NodeJS I should install *n_* [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n_).

So do I need both? Only one? Is one a superset to the other? Do I need **any** of them, really? (The site explains that it makes the life easier when working with JavaScript and arrays, so I guess I want it. But which?

I'm totally lost.

Comment: You want the `lodash` library. It looks like `n_` just wraps the standard Node repl to make `_` available (when the library usually conflicts with the debugger's own definition of `_`) -- more a convenience for developers who are jumping in and out of the shell constantly than something meant for production use.

Answer (score 1):

`n_` is a Node REPL that already has `lodash` built into it.

So if you want to use `lodash` in a project all you need is `lodash`.

The `n_` package is just an alternative REPL you can use that acts as if `lodash` is supported by Node.js natively